# Make default input values reactively reflect filtered dataset values

Tags: r, shiny

When I build a shiny app, I would like the default values of my filters to reflect the min and max of the working dataset.

For instance, is the app user filters to a specific subgroup (e.g., 4 cylinder cars), how can I reactively change the default values for min and max MPG in the inputs?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- 
    fluidPage(
        ## side panel
        #############################################################################
        sidebarPanel(
            pickerInput( 
                inputId = 'cyl',
                label = 'Cylinders',
                choices = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)
            ),
            numericInput("mpg_max", "MPG max", 50, min = 0, max = 50), # hardcoded max
            numericInput("mpg_min", "MPG min", 0, min = 0, max = 50), # hardcoded min
        ),
        ## main panel
        #############################################################################
        plotOutput("plot")
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        mtcars %>% 
            filter(
                cyl %in% input$cyl
                # between(mpg, input$mpg_min, input$mpg_max)
            ) %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
            geom_point() +
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(input$mpg_min, input$mpg_max))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If the user changes the Cylinder input to 4 there are no mpg values below 20, but I'm not sure how to update the default input values for `MPG min` with this info because reactive programming tends to happen in the `server` rather than `ui` area of a shiny app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

observeEvent() was the solution!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- 
    fluidPage(
        ## side panel
        #############################################################################
        sidebarPanel(
            pickerInput( 
                inputId = 'cyl',
                label = 'Cylinders',
                choices = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)
            ),
            numericInput("mpg_max", "MPG max", 50, min = 0, max = 50),
            numericInput("mpg_min", "MPG min", value = min(mtcars$mpg)-5, min = 0, max = 50),
        ),
        ## main panel
        #############################################################################
        plotOutput("plot")
    )

server <- function(session, input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$cyl, {
        x <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl %in% input$cyl) %>% summarise(min(mpg)) %>% pull()
        updateNumericInput(session, "mpg_min", value = x-5)
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        mtcars %>% 
            filter(
                cyl %in% input$cyl,
                between(mpg, input$mpg_min, input$mpg_max)
            ) %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
            geom_point() +
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(input$mpg_min, input$mpg_max))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]